# Cannot scaffold ionic project - template downloading 404?

Tags: ionic-framework

I keep getting the following error when trying to start a new ionic project. Is it a way to modify the url? I copied the url https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tab/archive/master.zip in browser and it also returns 404.

```
PS D:\Users\....\Source\Workspaces> ionic start app tab
Creating Ionic app in folder D:\Users\....\Source\Workspaces\app based on tab project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tab/archive/master.zip
Not found: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tab/archive/master.zip (404)
Please verify the url and try again.
Please verify you are using a valid URL or a valid ionic starter.
View available starter templates: `ionic start --list`
More info available at:
http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times since yesterday and it always got the same error. However, I closed the powershell window and opened a new one. And the error is gone. But why?